# How to delete "Google My Business" information that is not mine but its associate with me?

Tags: google-workspace, google-my-business

I was poking around the apps in Google Apps. It appears Google has made an incorrect association with a business and me. I'm trying to delete the association or record.

Google has an account page for this thing, but the web form seems to be predicated on its a valid association, so its asking me questions like, "How do you manage your business on Google". The answer is, *I don't, I didn't and I never have*. But the form won't allow me to proceed because it wants me to check something:

[image]

This particular app or settings page also appear to be locking me out of other settings because the Business Verification step has not been performed (its the red bar in the image below). And of course, the [Google My Business Help Center](http://support.google.com/business/?hl=en#topic=4540882) manages to avoid these topics altogether:

[image]

There is no Google Group for the Google My Business crap, so I can't go to the forum and ask how to get these broken records disassociated from me and my account.

Given the form is broken, Google does not appear to provide a support path, and Google does not allow me to make a real contact with a real person at the company, how do I have the association or record deleted from me and my account?

---

And the *Delete Page* does not submit either:

[image]

---

Related, I now suspect this broken Google association has been the source of an endless stream of unwanted telemarketing calls to my house. I have endured 100's of junk calls a week for years.

Has anyone had any luck hiring a lawyer to force Google to engage and act (rather than allowing them to hide behind broken web forms). I would be happy to immediately hire a lawyer and turn on Google now that I have hard evidence of the source.

I sincerely wish I had Larry Page and Sergey Brin's home and cell phone numbers so I could do the same to them. I would thoroughly enjoy seeing how they like being harassed for years without knowing the cause.

Comment: Have you tried to take ownership of the business and then delete it?

Comment: @Raystafarian - its not mine, so I won't take ownership.

Comment: I thought maybe it was an inactive one. Have you tried contacting the actual owner to let them take it?

Comment: @Raystafarian - I'm going to file suit against Google (either Friday or next week). They can spend $50,000 or $100,000 explaining why they are creating these problems for me and why their web forms are broken. I would have field this week, but I have to do it in Circuit court in Maryland. So I need the law center to look over the complaint and the motions.